# Sorting a list which contains numpy.ndarray elements PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, opencv

I'm working on a project of computer vision and I'd like to ask you something. I use `cv2.findContours()` the method then `approxPolyDP()` and I have 4-4 detected edges for every shape. There are three rectangles on the picture next to each other. The problem is, that I'd like to sort the list based on the first x,y coordinates. From left-to-right.

Thanks!

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(raw_image2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contour_list = []
for contour in contours:
    approx= cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.1*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)
    contur_list.append(approx)


   [array([[[383,  22]],

   [[384, 127]],

   [[492, 127]],

   [[491,  20]]], dtype=int32), array([[[ 54,  16]],

   [[ 52, 123]],

   [[160, 124]],

   [[160,  17]]], dtype=int32), array([[[222,  14]],

   [[220, 124]],

   [[328, 125]],

   [[328,  15]]], dtype=int32)]
```

That's the not sorted output, but I wish to be this one:

```
   [array([[[ 54,  16]],

   [[ 52, 123]],

   [[160, 124]],

   [[160,  17]]],dtype=int32), array([[[222,  14]],

   [[220, 124]],

   [[328, 125]],

   [[328,  15]]], dtype=int32), array([[[383,  22]],

   [[384, 127]],

   [[492, 127]],

   [[491,  20]]], dtype=int32)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the built-in function `sorted` like this:

```
sorted(contur_list, key=lambda approx: approx[0,0,0])
```

here the  `key` parameter specifies a function to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons. A `reversed` function can be called if you want a reversed version of the sorted list.